# How can I add @mentions in the discussion point of Azure Devops Bug using Power automate flow

Tags: automation, azure-devops, power-automate

I am planning to create a Devops Bug whenever the ADF pipeline fails and assigns it to respective owner and tag Support team in the discussion points. We have a static table where we maintains the owner and support team details. With the Power automate flow, I am able to achieve most of the things except tagging support team in discussion points.

I tried "Create a work item" connector in power automate, but couldn't see any option to tag alias in the discussion point of bug

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add @mentions in the discussion point of Azure Devops Bug using Power automate flow

I am afraid this feature is not supported in power automate at this time.

Personally think your needs are reasonable, you could submit your request to power automate ideas forum:

Power Automate Ideas: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/idb-p/MPAIdeas

Comment: Yeah, I have raised a request. Let's see if they can prioritize it.